# How do I determine and display the correct content page in .NET MAUI app at start up?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, content-pages

I'm new to .NET Maui and what I'm looking to do is at startup, check if there is any database files available. If there are, I want to display a popup page that has a list of those databases where the user can select a specific one to use in the app.

If no databases were found I want to display a page that will allow the user to create a new database.

I have a very basic understanding about MVVM and binding, but I noticed in the App.xaml and AppShell.xaml files seems to be where the content pages are executed.

So where do I go from here?

I noticed there is an OnStart method I can use in the App.xaml.cs file by doing something like:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
  base.OnStart();
  // add code here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
  base.OnStart();
  
  if (CheckDBExists()) 
  {
      MainPage = new SelectDBPage();
  }
  else
  {
      MainPage = new CreateDBPage();
  }
}
```